# Can you tell an image sequence when it should start playing?

Tags: image

In my animation I gave a short image sequence of an explosion. The image sequence is 25 frames long. My problem is that I don't want the image sequence to play until frame 120 of the blender project (ie the blender project is 400 frames long, at frame 120 I want the image sequence to start playing its 25 frames).

I cant simply loop the image sequence because the timing is off (ie by frame 120 of the blender project, the image sequence is off by 5 frames). I've tried the usual trickery of setting the offset of the sequence, but then I get 5 purple frames). I was hoping there was a node that allows me to specify when the image sequence should start playing, but I haven't found one yet.

Any suggestions are welcome!

- Jeff

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not difficult, you just need to understand the start & offset meanings in a Image Texture, Sequence node in the Shader Editor.  First add a node Texture :: Image Texture:

[image]

Then select any of the images in the sequence.  Once you've done this, you'll be able to select the Sequence from the Single Image drop-down:

[image]

I also fix up the image reference to be 'img ####' instead of a specific image (like "img 0000".   I then enter the number of frames that will be rendered by this scene & blend file.

For Start Frame, I enter the scene's frame where I want to rendered images to start to increment, pulling in subsequent frame images..

For Offset I might enter sometime other than 1 if I do not want to start the animation from the "img 0000" image.

[image]

If you do not want the "0000"th image to appear before you're Start Frame,  You'd also need to animate the rendering to disable before your desired start frame.  Here I did it inside the material shader nodes with a Math (Multiply) node (right click and add keyframe for the value you want at the frame you want:

[image]

Or you could animate the Render in the Outliner:

[image]

Comment: Wow! What an excellent answer! I didn't even know I could use the #### in the file name! Thanks a ton for your help.